# How do experimental physicists know the decay path of transuranium elements ahead of time?

Tags: radiation, elements, nucleosynthesis

I have been watching (and enjoying) Dr. Poliakoff's YouTube videos on the synthesis of transuranium elements like [Roentgenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roentgenium) and [Copernicium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernicium), which decay so quickly that they are identified (if I understand correctly) by their decay products.

As these elements have not been observed outside our laboratories, how do we know ahead of time that the newly-synthesized element will have a specific decay process, which yields expected decay products that can be matched up with the observed decay products seen in the lab?

Comment: I was reading John Wheeler's memoirs recently and he talked of modeling the atomic nucleus. Wheeler and Bohr worked on some calculations for U238 to show how feasible fission would be back before the manhattan project began. In the process, they hypothesized that a nucleus with 239 nucleons would much more readily undergo fission, a prediction which was exactly correct. It's not too surprising that 70-odd years later our models for nuclei are good enough to predict whether new elements will prefer alpha or beta decay.

Comment: @AlexReynolds there are a lot of nuclear models. There exists in principle a theory of nuclear reactions of Feshbach, and in its base are constructed different models, however, for the half-lives of different decay channels there are also semi-empirical formulas. I remember for instance predictions in base of the liquid-drop model. In many cases not the half-life is evaluated but the logarithm of the half-life, because the predictions cannot be very exact.